# How to disable https from wordpress site?

Tags: admin, migration, https

I have installed my wordpress instance on https://cti-uitutorials.rhcloud.com.

While changing the url to http://ctisleeperadi.in/ . all the admin related page still use the **https**, this resutls in warning of not secure site.

http://ctisleeperadi.in/

https://ctisleeperadi.in/wp-admin/

How do i change back all the admin related url to http instead of https?

Is it possible via phpMyAdmin or Theme function

Comment: How have you done the migration between domains?

Comment: CNAME with same hosting

Comment: [Any of this instructions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs)?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's in the wp_options table as 'home_url' and 'base_url', set both to start with http and Save the table in phpMyAdmin. If you can't login still, disable plugin by renaming the folder. Still failing, check htaccess file and wp-config files for forced security.